# while updating a row: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.tblRelatie' with unique index 'idxRelatiesoortRelatiecode'

Tags: sql-server-2005

when UPDATEing a row I get the above error. `idxRelatiesoortRelatiecode` consists of `fldRelatieSoort` and `fldRelatieSoort` and the combination of both exists only once in the table.

So what could be the reason for this error?

**Update**
Here is the update script

```
UPDATE [SQL].[MyDatabase].dbo.tblRelatie SET 
fldNaam = 'De heer A. Removed', 
fldAdres = 'Removed 12', 
fldPostcode = '1234 AA', fldPlaats = 'Removed', 
fldCorrespondentieAdres = 'Removed 12', 
fldCorrespondentieAdresPostcode = '1234 AA', 
fldCorrespondentieAdresPlaats = 'Removed', 
fldRelatieSoort = 1,
fldRelatiecode = 907534, 
fldCorrespondentieAdresLandID = 1, fldMobieleTelefoon = '', fldTelefoon = '', fldFax = '',  fldEmail = '', fldWebsiteUrl = '', fldBankrekeningnummer = '', fldNaamRekeninghouder = '', 
fldPlaatsRekeninghouder = '', fldKrediettermijn = 30, fldLandID = 1 
WHERE fldRelatieID =1507;
```

and this is the idxRelatiesoortRelatiecode:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idxRelatiesoortRelatiecode] 
ON [dbo].[tblRelatie] 
(
    [fldRelatieSoort] ASC,
    [fldRelatiecode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,    
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't much ambiguity in the error message: you **are** setting a duplicate somewhere

- Either: the combination already exists and you are trying to insert it again
- Or: it doesn't exist and you are updating multiple rows with the same combination

Or the overlap:

- the combination already exists and you are updating multiple rows with the same combination

Unless the index or such is wrong...

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but when I queried for both indexed columns, it returned exactly one row: the row I am updating

Comment: How many rows with `SELECT * FROM dbo.tblRelatie WHERE fldRelatieID =1507` and `SELECT * FROM dbo.tblRelatie WHERE fldRelatieSoort = 1 AND fldRelatiecode = 907534`?

Comment: 1 row each. Of course there are multiple rows for `SELECT * FROM dbo.tblRelatie WHERE fldRelatieSoort = 1` because relatiesoort (relationship type) is sort of an enum.

Comment: Combining the 2: `SELECT * FROM dbo.tblRelatie WHERE fldRelatieID =1507 AND fldRelatieSoort = 1 AND fldRelatiecode = 907534`

Comment: Zero rows. Because fldRelatieID = 3707 for `fldRelatieSoort = 1 AND fldRelatiecode = 907534`. That is the problem. Thank you so much. Now I know where to look

Comment: There is ambiguity in the error message. It implies that there is a rogue INSERT command somewhere, when it is simply an UPDATE command. Your terminology, "setting", is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

In my case case there's a constraint on the table, the constraint is like this

```
ALTER TABLE {my_table}
   ADD CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_ID} UNIQUE (my_table.colA, my_table.colB)
```

I am trying to update a data that is already existing (colA and colB), so I just have to check if the data im trying to update is present.