# EF Core 3.1 duplicate key exception unique index

Tags: c#, .net-core, sql-server-2016, ef-core-3.1

I face this error in EF Core 3.1 with a SQL SErver 2016 backend:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.table1' with unique index 'ix_mobile'. The duplicate key value is (+1, 11111)

This is happening inconsistent with about 40 times out of 1000 times. What am I doing wrong here? `DbContext` is a DI injected single instance.

```
var user = dbContext.table1.AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(x => x.id== "zyz").SingleOrDefault();

if (user != null)
{
    user.Mobile = "11111";
    user.CountryCode = "+1";

    dbContext.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Here Am trying to update the entry not insert. For Example : Mobile number "11111" exists for an Id 2. Am retrieving a row with Id value 2 having Mobile Number "11111" and updating the same row with same Mobile Number. Should it throw error? This error is happening inconsistent with about 40 times out of 1000 times. FYI, there are no other records with the same mobile number.

Comment: You already have such a row in your table with the same values for `Mobile` and `CountryCode`. Check the existing entries in your table.

Comment: You have mobile property as unique index in your table and every time you call SaveChangesAsync() with value 11111, it generates error that this value is already present. Either remove unique index constraint from Mobile or update with unique value every time.

Comment: @Progman Am trying to update the entry not insert. For Example : Mobile number "11111" exists for an Id 2. Am retrieving a row with Id value 2 having Mobile Number "11111" and updating the same row with same Mobile Number. Should it throw error? This error is happening inconsistent with about 40 times out of 1000 times. FYI, there are no other records with the same mobile number.

Comment: @Raj Setting the exact same value doesn't trigger this error. But changing the column to that value can trigger the error if the value is already used. And the value `+1,11111` already exists in the table, otherwise the database wouldn't reject your query, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6744736/286934. Also check other parallel running queries which might change the value when you don't expect it. If you can't find the problem, please provide a [mcve], see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/286934.

Comment: @Progman Thanks for your response. The problem is that we couldnt reproduce this issue. It occurs only in our production environment and very inconsistently. Am able to pull this issue from the logs. And also am sure that we dont have same number in database already, verified this with multiple numbers taken from error logs.

Comment: @Raj Yes, you can't have the same number twice in the database because you have a `UNIQUE` constraint in the database. And if you try to insert/update a row with an already existing number you get an key violation error, as expected and as you already did. The database is working as intended and the `UNIQUE` constraint is working as it should. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but difficult to say without the full code and/or a MCVE of the problem.